# php flash wont go away even when the code is deleted

Tags: php, flash

i am watching a login and register page tutorial i was using a flash to say that a user has been successfully registered and now i'm testing redirecting to a error page and the guy in the tutorial doesn't delete the flash code and the flash doesn't appear  and it the contents of the custom 404 error page still appears for mine the flash still remains even if i leave the flash and change the echo message it echo's the first the old one still.

this is the flash

```
Session::flash('home', 'You have been registered and can now login');
```

even if this line and the contents of index.php is deleted it will still redirect to index.php

register code

```
if(Input::exists()) {

    if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {

        $validate = new Validate();
        $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
            'username' => array(
                'required' => true,
                'min' => 6,
                'max' => 20,
                'unique' => 'users'
            ),
            'password' => array(
                'required' => true,
                'min' => 6
            ),
            'password_again' => array(
                'required' => true,
                'matches' => 'password'
            ),
            'name' => array(
                'required' => true,
                'min' => 2,
                'max' => 50
            )
        ));

        if($validation->passed()) {
            $user = new User();

            $salt = Hash::salt(32);



            try {

                $user->create(array(
                    'username' => Input::get('username'),
                    'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password'), $salt),
                    'salt' => $salt,
                    'name' => Input::get('name'),
                    'joined' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                    'group' => 1
                ));
                Session::flash('home', 'You have been registered and can now login');
                Redirect::to(404);



            }catch(Exception $e) {
                die($e->getMessage());
            }

        } else {
            foreach ($validation->errors() as $error) {
                echo $error, '<br>';
            };
        }
    }
}
?>
<form action ="" method= "post">
    <div class="field">
        <label for= "username">Username</label>
        <input type= "text" name= "username" id ="username" value="<?php echo escape(Input::get('username')); ?>" autocomplete="off">
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <label for="password">Choose a password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password">

    <div class="field">
        <label for="password_again">Confirm password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password_again" id="password_again">

    <div class="field">
        <label for= "name">Name</label>
        <input type= "text" name= "name" value="<?php echo escape(Input::get('name')); ?>" id ="name">
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

Redirect.php

```
<?php
class Redirect {
    public static function to($location = null) {
        if($location) {
            if(is_numeric($location)) {
                switch($location) {
                    case 404:
                        header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not found');
                        include 'includes/errors/404.php';
                        exit();
                        break;
                }
            }
            header('Location: ' . $location);
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

404.php

```
this page was not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand this correctly, but the `Redirect::to(404);` code directs you to the 404 page, and includes a 404.php file.

Deleting the line `Session::flash('home', 'You have been registered and can now login');` or the contents of the index.php will not stop this happening.